# How to initialize a private char * in a Class constructor with user input upon instantiation

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, constructor

The following program crashes in the constructor definition. Apparently I can't use the constructor to copy the given string into the **brand** variable into the private class variable _brand.

Where am I going wrong here? The idea is to take user input for the brand name, and instantiate the class with this name as _brand.

EDIT: Please don't advise use of the **std::string** class, as I'm stuck with c-strings on this one. This is a tiny piece of an assignment for an intermediate C++ University class. The Professor wants us to have a foundation in C-strings before we move on to the STL string class. The instructions specifically forbid the use of std::string. Thx.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class Cheese {
    char * _brand;
public:
    Cheese(const char *); // constructor declaration
    char * getBrand();
};
Cheese::Cheese(char const * b) { // constructor definition
    strcpy(_brand, b); // CRASHES HERE
}
char * Cheese::getBrand() {
     return _brand;
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    const char * brand = "Cabot";
    Cheese * cheddar = new Cheese(brand);
    std::cout << cheddar -> getBrand();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not tag your titles.

Answer (score 4):

As other have pointed out, `_brand` is just a **pointer**. It doesn't store a string, it points to a memory address where the strings starts. That memory space is something you must reserve.

The solution is quite simple:

```
_brand = new char[strlen(b)+1]; // Reserve memory chunk for your copied string. Add +1 for string terminator '\0'
strcpy(_brand, b); // "CRASHES HERE" should be gone now
```

By saying **new**, _brand variable now points to a valid chunk of memory (owned by your program), large enough to store your copied string.

At the end, don't forget to **free** `_brand` to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Evidently the solution *isn't* quite so simple, your code has a bug, you don't account for the null terminator. You need `new char[strlen(b) + 1]`. And what you really need is `std::string`, despite the arbitrary restrictions placed by the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. +1 should be there indeed. I edited my answer.
And I couldn't agree more, `std::string` should be used.

Comment: This is part of an assignment for an intermediate C++ University class. The instructions specifically state that use of the stl:string class is forbidden. Professor wants us to understand C-strings before moving on to the STL.

Comment: That's a terrible idea. It makes more sense to teach the simple before the complex. You need a better teacher. (Not to mention that `string` was never part of the STL. It's part of the standard library.)

Comment: @kmiklas I realize you don't have much say in what's taught in class, but your professor is going about this backwards. *Understanding C-strings and then moving on to `std`* helps reinforce the misconception that C++ is an extension of C, and not a completely different language. You should be taught to write good C++ first using the standard library, and then move on to the nitty gritty details of manual memory management. In any case, don't forget to follow the Rule of Three for your class, it needs a destructor and copy assignment operator.

Answer (score 3):

`_brand` is just a pointer and has no memory allocated behind it when your class is created. At the point when you try to do `strcpy` to it, it will likely be `NULL` or point to memory that your program has no access to and hence it crashes. You can use `strdup` which allocates the memory, but then you will have to `free` this later, for example in the destructor. Best is to use the standard C++ `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

In C and C++ a pointer points to a location in memory. Accessing the pointer allows you to read to and write from the location it points to. In your program the member `_brand` is a pointer that hasn't been initialized, it's not defined where it points to. Reading from and writing to an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior, which means everything and nothing can happen. This often means the program will crash, but because the behavior is undefined the outcome can be far worse - it could really write to a random location in memory, for example.

You need actual memory instead of just a pointer. Here are 3 reasonable ways:

Array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class Cheese {
    char _brand[256];
public:
    Cheese(const char *); // constructor declaration
    char * getBrand();
};
Cheese::Cheese(char const * b) { // constructor definition
    strncpy(_brand, b, sizeof(_brand)); // copies up to 255 characters, plus terminating \0
}
char * Cheese::getBrand() {
     return _brand;
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    const char * brand = "Cabot";
    Cheese * cheddar = new Cheese(brand);
    std::cout << cheddar -> getBrand();
    delete cheddar;
    return 0;
}
```

Pointer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class Cheese {
    char * _brand;
public:
    Cheese(const char *); // constructor declaration
    ~Cheese(); // destructor declaration
    char * getBrand();
};
Cheese::Cheese(char const * b) { // constructor definition        
    _brand = new char[strlen(b)+1];
    strcpy(_brand, b);  
}
Cheese::~Cheese() { // destructor definition 
    if (_brand != nullptr) // if you add another constructor that doesn't set _brand, make sure to set _brand to nullptr
        delete _brand; // if we don't free here there's a memory leak
}
char * Cheese::getBrand() {
     return _brand;
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    const char * brand = "Cabot";
    Cheese * cheddar = new Cheese(brand);
    std::cout << cheddar -> getBrand();
    delete cheddar; 
    return 0;
}
```

Smart Pointer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <memory>

class Cheese {
    std::unique_ptr<char> _brand; 
public:
    Cheese(const char *); // constructor declaration
    char * getBrand();
};
Cheese::Cheese(char const * b) { // constructor definition        
    _brand = new char[strlen(b)+1]; // smart pointer will free any memory assigned to it on destruction
    strcpy(_brand, b);  
}
char * Cheese::getBrand() {
     return _brand.get();
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    const char * brand = "Cabot";
    Cheese * cheddar = new Cheese(brand);
    std::cout << cheddar -> getBrand();
    delete cheddar;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You missed the actual strcpy.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this out. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot copy the data because in your class declaration you have just reserved a pointer, but you have not set it to point at anything. What I mean is when you call your constructor the object will just have a size of 4 bytes in memory which will hold a pointer to nowhere.

to solve this you can change the declaration of your `brand` variable into a `char[]` array but it a bad solution.

Comment: It's normally called an array. And that would just make the program ill-formed; you can't define a member with an incomplete type.

Comment: Declaring `brand` as an array of characters is not bad.  You just have to specify its max number of characters, and then use `strncpy()` instead so you don't exceed that size.